# "Learn more" link in review queue page is not responding on "Stats" and "History" tabs

Tags: bug, status-completed, review, popups

There is a "Learn more" link available on all the review queue pages, clicking on it opens a popup with that review queue's information.
That "Learn more" link is responding in the ["Review tasks"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/review/close) tab only. If we are navigating to [Stats](https://meta.stackexchange.com/review/close/stats) or [History](https://meta.stackexchange.com/review/close/history) tab, the link is not responding.
As an example I linked the Close vote review queue, but the issue exists for all the review queues.

Either enable the popup for the [Stats](https://meta.stackexchange.com/review/close/stats) and [History](https://meta.stackexchange.com/review/close/history) tabs, or remove the "Learn more" link line for those two tabs.

**Sample screenshot of Close votes review queue popup:**

[image: Close votes review queue popup]

Comment: Already reported here: [New onboarding for review queues](/a/364060/289905); also reported on MSO: [Broken “Learn More” link on Suggested edits page](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/407777/4642212).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

It seems the bug had been fixed sometime before.

Now, when clicking on the "Learn more" link from the [Stats](https://meta.stackexchange.com/review/close/stats) or [History](https://meta.stackexchange.com/review/close/history) tab, the popup opens correctly.

**Screenshot for reference:**

[image: Learn more opens the popup]